# Need Start time & End time of Approval Process in Opportunity Object

Tags: reporting, approval-process, dashboard

Can anybody please tell me how to show start Time and End Time of Approval Process in standard Opportunity Object ?

i need that thing to track flow of Opportunity in Report.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding Field Update steps to the start and end of your approval process. These field updates can populate start time and end time fields that you create on the opportunity object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but may i know what should be the formula of that field ?

Comment: The 'Approval Start Time' and 'Approval End Time' fields will be Date/Time fields you create on the Opportunity object. In the Initial Submission Actions section of the Approval Process, add a new Field Update step that updates the 'Approval Start Time' field with the formula Now()  . In the same way, add a Field Update step to the Final Approval Actions section that updates the 'Approval End Time' field.